# api.whatsapp.com/send: Safari cannot open page because the address is invalid

Tags: objective-c, iphone, safari, whatsapp

I'm trying to use `Whatsapp's` web API to send text to any valid number (even numbers that are not in my contacts list). If the user has the `Whatsapp` app installed, it will open. Else, the browser will open.

In Xcode, simulating an iPhone, the problem is that when Safari opens the URL, I get a popup message `Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid`.
But the address is actually correct and the correct page has loaded behind the popup. I don't understand what the problem is. What do I have to do to not get this popup?

Here's the snippet I'm using in a view-controller:

```
NSString * plainString = @"https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=5511123456789&text=Hello";
NSString * encodedString = [plainString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL * whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:encodedString];

if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:whatsappURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:whatsappURL];
}
```

I also added `whatsapp` to the `LSApplicationQueriesStrings` in `Info.plist`.

- I started learning `Objective-C` last week, I have literally no idea how to use other similar answers to solve this.

Comment: The official WhatsApp documentation advises to use the following URL `https://wa.me/<number>`, however the problem you have described still exists, and I haven't managed to solve it yet.

Comment: Thanks, Tomasz. Unfortunately, I believe I'll have to think of an alternative flow. :(

Comment: this article has some information on it but not working either: https://www.androidpolice.com/2020/04/08/3-ways-to-message-a-number-on-whatsapp-without-adding-them-as-a-contact-first/